# De Macro a VBA para crear desde Access Gráfico de Barra Apilada en Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros, gráficas

Desde MS Access 2016 exporto una Consulta a Excel.
La Consulta qry123, tiene las siguientes columnas:
 A B C D E
En esa Hoja(qry123) necesito crear una Gráfica de Barra Apilada.
A la fecha no he logrado entender el significado de:

.SeriesCollection(x).Values
.SeriesCollection(x).XValues
En mi caso para crear la gráfica grabé esta Macro en Excel:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlBarStacked).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=qry_123!$A$2:$A$15"

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "=qry_123!$C$2:$C$15"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=qry_123!$E$2:$E$15"
```

Pero, no he podido escribir en VBA su equivalente en las siguientes líneas de codigo VBA:

```
With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlBarStacked
        .HasTitle = True
        .HasLegend = False            

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown)

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = ws.Range("C2", ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown))
```

.
.
.
End with

Agradezco que me ayuden a entender el uso de seriescolletion en el Gráfico de Barra Apliada y a escribir de manera correcta la Macro en código VBA para crear dicho Gráfico.

La hoja está definida así:

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_123")
```

Saludos

Comment: ¿Has probado a meter un string con la dirección del rango, en vez de meter el rango completo? Por ejemplo, en vez de `ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown))` prueba con `"=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)` y así con los demás `values`, a ver qué pasa

Comment: Al correr el código: `.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ws.qry_123 & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)´

VBA muestra Error de Compilación: No se encontró el método o el dato miembro
Se colorea de azul esta instrucción: `.qry_123´

Comment: Agrego que tengo esta declaración:
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("qry_123")
Por lo anterior, probé este código:
`.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ws & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)´
Ocurre el Error 438 en tiempo de ejecusión: El Objeto no admite esta propiedad o método 
Marca de amarillo todo el Código.

Comment: Finalmente, al usar este código:
`.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ws.Range("qry_123") & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)´
Muestra el Error 13 en tiempo de ejecusión: No coinciden los tipos.
Toda la línea se colorea de amarillo.

Aprecio su ayuda para escribir el código correctamente.

Comment: Tienes que usar `ws.name` justo antes del símbolo `!`. Fíjate en mi primer comentario que yo lo puse justo después del `=` y tú en los tuyos no.

Comment: Copié y pegué el siguiente código, según lo indicado:
`.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)´

La hoja excel abre y muestra la consulta. Pero da este Error 1004 'Parámetro no válido', en la línea de código arriba indicada
Me disculpo por mis errores, pero, durante dos semanas he estado estudiando y probando muchos códigos, sin embargo, en todos los casos siempre ocurre un error en la misma línea de Código.
Aprecio su ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: Lo estás poniendo en `.SeriesCollection(2).Values ` que, según tu código, ahí va la columna C, y yo, lo que te he puesto, era solo para la columna A, así que debería ir con `.SeriesCollection(1).Values `

Comment: @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes
Tu Código Funciona: 
`.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
`.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)
Traté programar Col(3):
`.SeriesCollection.NewSeries`
`.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlC1, False)`

Pero,  `xlC1´ da Error de Compilación. No se ha definido la variable.
xlA1 corre, xlC1 no
Agradezco, la ayuda para corregir mi error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el resto tienes que adaptar el código según la columna:

```
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)
    .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=" & ws.Name & "!" & ws.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(ws.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Address(True, True, xlA1, False)
```

Adapta el código a tus necesidades y asegurate de que estás llamando a las celdas y columnas que quieres.

Comment: Sánchez E-Infante. Voy a probar las lineas de código que me recomiendas. Te aviso. Aprecio tu ayuda.

Comment: Al fin pude adaptar el Código que me recomendaste. Corre beien. Saludos.

Comment: ¡Me alegra que funcione!